# ArrayList of ArrayLists: Check That Each ArrayList Has Same Number of Items

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of ArrayLists. I want to make sure that each of the constituent ArrayLists has the same number of items. Is there any way to do this in less than n! time?

Comment: Why would this take O(n!) time?

Comment: Because I had been writing simple code for too long, and my mind melted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely!  Iterate over the `ArrayList`s one at a time.  Store the size of the first `ArrayList`, then confirm that the sizes of all the other `ArrayList`s match the size of the first list.  Total time required is O(n), where n is the number of lists.

For example:

```
public static boolean listsHaveSameSize(List<List<?>> allLists) {
    List<?> first = null;
    for (List<?> list: allLists) {
        if (first == null) {
             first = list;
        } else if (list.size() != first.size()) {
             return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You need to be careful with the `else` branch--`list` can be `null`.

Comment: @TedHopp- I was assuming that the top-level list didn't contain any null lists; is it unreasonable to assume this?

Comment: Dunno if it's unreasonable, but coding defensively isn't such a burden here. It just needs a separate `else if (list == null) { return false; }` step. If OP needs to check the contents for consistency, then there isn't 100% control over the contents of the top list to start with, so it seems prudent to me. By the way, it might be a good idea to store the size of `first` once it isn't `null` and use that instead of repeatedly calling `size()`.

Comment: @TedHopp it really is about the contract isn't it? I would rather throw `NPE` then have tons of `if (...!= null)` in my code

Comment: @MiserableVariable - Absolutely it's about contract. There are several possibilities: a `null` list could be ignored; it could be treated as an empty list; it could force a `false` return value (perhaps only if there was also at least one non-`null` element); it could throw an NPE. Any one of these might make sense, depending on the context. Since no contract was specified, I was simply pointing out that the code (as written) assumed the last possibility.